# How can I fix this syntax error when importing functions from another library

Tags: python, syntax-error, pid

I get a syntax error of `SyntaxError: can't assign to function call` located on the genwave function's self.rp.set line. How can I get rid of this error?

```
  import time
  import rp
  import numpy as np
  import pyrpl

class PID:
    """PID Controller"""

def __init__(self, P=0.2, I=0.0, D=0.0, current_time=None):

    self.Kp = P
    self.Ki = I
    self.Kd = D
    self.sample_time = 0.00
    self.current_time = current_time if current_time is not None else time.time()
    self.last_time = self.current_time
    self.targetT = targetT

    self.clear()
    
def genwave(self, out_channel, waveform, voltage, offset):
    '''generates analog waveform out of the redpitaya from OUT 1'''
    self.rp.analog()
    self.rp.set(self, 0, voltage) = out_voltage
    self.rp.funct_gen()
    self.rp.set_waveform(self, 1, waveform) = wave_output
    self.rp.set_amplitude(self, 1, voltage) = wave_amplitude
    self.rp.set_offset(self,1, offset) = voltage_offset
```

Comment: You are trying to assign a value to a function call `self.rp.set(self, 0, voltage) = out_voltage`. This is not possible. What exactly are you trying to do ? Also your code indent seems off

Comment: Can you show us the error message?

Comment: @Andrej see edit

Answer (score 0):

The error says it all here:

```
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

`self.rp.set` is being called and then being assigned a value of `out_voltage`. Calling the function usually returns value, this is contrary to how a function works.

I'm not sure what `self.rp.set` actually does or returns, or what `out_voltage` is but it almost looks like the expression should be flipped on the equal sign, but then the function never does anything with `out_voltage` so kind of hard to say. BTW this error will occur for more function calls in `genwave`.

For example:

```
>>> int() = 0
  File "<stdin>", line 1
SyntaxError: can't assign to function call
```

Answer (score 0):

You are assigning a value to a function and that is not possible,

You can try anything like `self.rp.set = out_voltage(self, 0, voltage)`
but not this `self.rp.set(self, 0, voltage) = out_voltage`

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign a value to a function.
You probably meant to say:
`out_voltage = self.rp.set(self, 0, voltage)`